# Invertibility of Cellular Automata over $A^G$ for locally finite G.

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces, cellular-automata

This is an exercise from "Cellular Automata and Groups" by T. Ceccherini-Silberstein and M. Coornaert.

Let $G$ be a locally finite group and let $A$ be an arbitrary set. Let $\tau: A^G \rightarrow A^G$ be a bijective cellular automata ie

(1) that $\tau$ is $G$-equivariant under the action of $G$ on $A^G$ given by $g(x(h)) = x(hg^{-1})$, so, $g\tau(x) = \tau(gx)$ and

(2) that $\tau$ is uniformly continuous with respect to the prodiscrete uniform space equipped to $A^G$.

(or equivalently $\tau$ is $G$-equivariant and there exists finite "memory set" $S \subset G$ and a map $\mu :A^{s} \rightarrow A$ such that $\tau(x)(g) = \mu(g^{-1}x|_{S})$ for the group action above.

I am trying to show that it must be that $\tau^{-1}$ is also a cellular automata. But I am not sure how $G$ being locally finite gets us there.
I do have a couple of observations: first, we can assume $A$ is infinite, since the finite case is trivial. Second is that if we let $S$ be the memory set of $\tau$, then $H = \langle S \rangle$ is finite, and I know that $\tau$ is invertible iff the restriction of $\tau$ to $H$ is invertible, and it might be that it is easier to work with $A^H$ with $H$ finite (showing that $\tau^{-1}$ is uniformly continuous) or maybe we get nice some property forced on $A^H$ as a prodiscrete topological or prodiscrete uniform space.

What am I missing?

Comment: Almost there!  The map $\tau_H$ induced on $A^H$ is a bijection and the inverse $\tau_H^{-1}$ induces a map on $A^G$ which is the inverse of $\tau$ and has memory set $H$.

Comment: @Blackbird I know that I have $\tau^{-1}$ is a cellular automataiff $\tau_{H}^{-1}$ is also, but that is where I am stuck -- showing that $\tau_{H}^{-1}$ is also a cellular automata.

Comment: Is this true because $H$ is finite, and so we take $\tau^{-1}_{H}(x)(h)$ as the local rule and $H$ as the memory set, and see that it is well defined because agreeing on $H$ in $A^{H}$ is just being the same configuration?

Comment: Yes, you got it!